# Go - JSON validation throwing error unless I use pointer in the struct. Why?

Tags: json, validation, go

Here is my validation structure:

```
type PostEmail struct {
    Username       string `json:"username" validate:"required"`
    Email          string `json:"email" validate:"required"`
    IsRefreshEmail *bool  `json:"isRefreshEmail" validate:"required"`
}
```

I'm pointing the value of `IsRefreshEmail` with `*bool`. If I remove the pointer and I try to call my API without it, the API will throw a bad syntax error.
That will happen only if the boolean value will be `false`. If it's `true` even if you remove the pointer the API will respond correctly.

Why is this happening? It's normal? I can't understand it and i don't even know if I'm doing it wrong with the pointer. What I surely know is that if I remove the `*` from `bool` and I insert `false` as value in postman for the field `isRefreshEmail` the API will throw an exception.

Someone can explain please? Thank you.

Comment: What is the exact error message?

Comment: default value for bool is false, so if it `false` it will be considered no value and validation will throw error for it

Comment: @HymnsForDisco `field validation for isRefreshEmail failed on the 'required' tag`

Comment: @RahmatFathoni that does not make too much sens cause I wanna be able to override the default value even with another default value, but that is not importan, like you said I tried to remove the validation from that field and it worked, so now by default event if I dont send nothing for `isRefreshEmail` the value will be false. thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A boolean can represent two values, `false` or `true`:

```
var IsRefreshEmail bool
```

A boolean pointer can represent three values, `false`, `true` or `nil`:

```
var IsRefreshEmail *bool
```

The benefit of this, is that you can compare `false` with `nil`:

```json
{"email": "hello", "isRefreshEmail": false}
{"email": "hello"}
```

without the pointer, the two JSON above will be identical after Unmarshal.
Depending on your situation, you might not care about that. However if you need
to know if the value was omitted, then pointer is required.

Answer (score 2):

Default value of bool is false

Default value of *bool is nil

So when using with pointer and the value you send is false -> fasle

But when use with bool -> you send false -> validate with check and make it failure validation(same as default value)

The problem is same for int and *int with the 0 value